# create faceted plots 2-way interaction in R using 'interactions' package

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the cat_plot function from the 'interactions' package in R (which is a wrapper for ggplot) to plot a 2-way interaction with 2 categorical variables. I can do this easily using the code below (reprex from the "diamonds" dataset)

```
require(interactions)

data("diamonds")

m <- glm(price ~ cut*color, data = diamonds)

cat_plot(m, pred = cut, modx = color, geom = "bar", colors = "Set1")
```

This produces the following graph

[image: graph of colour by cut]

However, what I would like is to have a faceted graph with each of the cuts presented separately, to make it visually easier to interpret. This can be done for 3-way interactions using the `facet.modx = TRUE` command, but when I try this with only a 2-way interaction with `cat_plot(m, pred = cut, modx = color, geom = "bar", colors = "Set1", facet.modx = TRUE)` I get the following error

```
Error in prep_data(model = model, pred = pred, modx = modx, pred.values = pred.values,  : 
  formal argument "facet.modx" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

Is there a way to easily facet the graph for 2 way interactions? My real-life dataset is actually a glmer model so I would prefer to stay within the "interactions" package if possible.

EDIT: based on the suggestion from @stefan I tried the following syntax `cat_plot(m, pred = cut, modx = color, geom = "bar", colors = "Set1") + facet_wrap(~cut)` which produced the graph below. This is almost exactly what I want, except it has seemed to keep the other 'cuts' on the x-axis and just removed the bars. Ideally, colours would be on the x-axis instead.

[image]

EDIT 2:

I have recreated the problem using data which is more similar to what I am actually working with, with a binary outcome, random effects from glmer etc.

```
require(lme4)
require(interactions)

set.seed(123)
id <- rep(1:150, each = 4)
condition <- rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 4, times = 50)
cat_mod <- rep(c("cat_1", "cat_2", "cat_3", "cat_4"), each = 1, length.out = 600)
control_mod <- rep(c("control_1", "control_2"), each = 4, length.out = 600)
binary_choice <- rbinom(600, 1, 0.5)


simdat <- data.frame(id, condition, cat_mod, binary_choice, control_mod)

m <- glmer(binary_choice ~ condition*cat_mod + control_mod + (1 | id), family=binomial, data = simdat)

cat_plot(m, pred = condition, modx = cat_mod, geom = "bar", colors = "Set1")
```

[image]

I would like to preserve the response scale on the y-axis, and the model accounting for the random intercept, which is why I was trying to avoid using ggplot directly, as the interactions package is already built to accommodate glmms, which is super convenient.

**SOLVED**

Following the suggestion from @RStam I modified the code slightly so that all y-axes had the same scale, and removed the duplicate facet labels at the bottom.

```
cat_plot(m, pred = condition, modx = cat_mod, geom = "bar", colors = "Set1") + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c(a = " ", b = " ", c = " ")) + 
  facet_wrap(condition~., scales= "free_x")
```

This was the final result

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell from the docs `cat_plot` has no arguement `facet.modx`. But you could try with e.g. `+ facet_wrap(~cut)`

Comment: @stefan you are correct facet_modx is not an argument for for cat_plot, but it is for interact_plot, which is why I tried it. cat_plot has the argument ```mod2.values``` which, from what I can gather, is for faceting in 3-way interactions. That being said, I tried adding ```cat_plot(m, pred = cut, modx = color, geom = "bar", colors = "Set1") + facet_wrap(~cut)``` which kind of worked, except that it seems to have done some weird formatting (I've edited the question description)

Comment: In that case: try with `+ facet_wrap(~cut, scales = "free_x")` which should only keep  the categories which are present in a panel.

Comment: I just replied to @RStam below, who made the same suggestion. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, it produces the same output as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original Answer**

```
cat_plot(m, pred = cut, modx = color, geom = "bar", colors = "Set1") + 
facet_wrap(~cut, scales = "free_x")
```

**Edit 1**

After that it still wasn't resolving your issue I've updated my answer. This should resolve the issue you are having.

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=color,y=price, fill = color)) +
geom_col() + facet_wrap(~cut, scales = "free")
```

**Edit 2**

Using your new data and the interactions package I found a rather unpleasant 'hack' using scale_x_discrete() but it should give the desired outcome.

```
library(interactions)
library(lme4)

set.seed(123)
id <- rep(1:150, each = 4)
condition <- rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 4, times = 50)
cat_mod <- rep(c("cat_1", "cat_2", "cat_3", "cat_4"), each =  
1, length.out = 600)
control_mod <- rep(c("control_1", "control_2"), each = 4, 
length.out = 600)
binary_choice <- rbinom(600, 1, 0.5)


simdat <- data.frame(id, condition, cat_mod, binary_choice, 
control_mod)

m <- glmer(binary_choice ~ condition*cat_mod + control_mod + 
(1 | id), family=binomial, data = simdat)

cat_plot(m, pred = condition, modx = cat_mod, geom = "bar", 
colors = "Set1") + scale_x_discrete() + 
facet_wrap(condition~., scales= "free")
```

Comment: unfortunately not :( it produces exactly the same output as ```cat_plot(m, pred = cut, modx = color, geom = "bar", colors = "Set1") + facet_wrap(~cut)```

Comment: @becbot I've updated my answer to directly use ggplot. Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: thank you so much! Unfortunately the actual data / model I am working with is a bit more complex, which is why I was aiming to use the interactions package, rather than ggplot directly, as it is already built to accommodate these models. However for the reprex which I initially posted this would definitely work :)

Comment: @becbot See Edit 2